# Spotify Web API to control playback on connect devices

Tags: api, asp.net-web-api, spotify, libspotify

Is there any way to use an API to control playback on my registered spotify connect devices? I'm not trying to create or add a new connect devices but control playback to them.

Is there any official or reverse engineering discussion on how to do this?

[image: Playing from a wave device in bedroom]

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, there is no way to do this currently.

That said, it's also unclear if or when this feature will be added.  Spotify hasn't updated its api code in months.  It also appears that the login functionality is broken on my app too.  Spotify doesn't seem to be easy to work with.